# Expression, bquote and inequality sign

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to print a "greater or equal to" sign an an R base plot. I have tried both with expression() and bquote() and I simply do not understand what is going wrong.

There is no need for long code, according to plotmath documenmtation this

```
expression(>=)
```

should return a vector of type "expression" containing its arguments (unevaluated). Therefore, it should return expression(>=). As is the case for

```
> expression(phi)  
expression(phi)
```

I keep getting

```
> expression(>=)  
Error: unexpected '>=' in "expression(>="
```

irrespective of the surrounding code.

Comment: The same happens with `rlang::expr(>=)`. I guess you just can't save an invalid expression. As `>=` is an operator, it needs arguments to turn into a valid expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap >= in backquotes, which turns the symbol into a name, but it will be displayed as two symbols, not one. Use `expression("" >= "")` to get the symbol you probably want.  For example,

```r
plot(1, xlab = expression(`>=`), ylab = expression("" >= ""))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>